# Dynamic Data Website - Hide columns in gridview but show in details?

Tags: gridview, web, customization, dynamic-data

I have seen how you can hide a column by scaffolding. But how about hiding it from the gridview only and showing it on the details screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a FormView to details page dynamically.

this link may help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.formview.aspx

Comment: http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/10/dynamic-data-hiding-columns-in-selected.html

This web page answered my question and a lot more.

Thanks!